# Problem with branch specification (The build was triggered in the branch XXX which does not correspond to any branch monitored by the build VCS roots)

Tags: teamcity

good day. i try to ask same question on teamcity support forum but with no luck, so i try to find solution here
i have 4 (actual more, but other configuration not important for the situation):

- 'verify' - configuration that run test, check that all migration can be applied to database (run in docker) etc. this configuration triggered by gitlab (integration with teamcity feature)
- 'build' - configuration that build all application components and push docker images to hub
- 'deploy to test' - use corresponded artifacts from 'build' configuration and perform deploy images to test server
- 'deploy to staging' - same as 'deploy to test' but use staging server
- 'deploy to production' - same as 'deploy to production' but use production server

we have several stream in out repository with corresponded rules:

- develop
- feature/* - feature task that should be build then corresponded merge request to develop was initiated. merged to develop
- release/* - release that should be deployed to staging server at each commit. merged to develop and master
- hotfix/* - hotfix that should be deployed to staging server at each commit. merged into develop and master
- master - stable branch, should be deployed to production on commit.

so, i create following VCS root:

default branch: `refs/heads/develop`

branch specification:

```
+:refs/heads/(*)
+:refs/heads/master
+:refs/heads/release/*
+:refs/heads/feature/*
+:refs/heads/hotfix/*
+:refs/(merge-requests/*)
```

after that i setup branch filters (for VCS Trigger) for each branch configuration:

- verify - none
- build:

```
+:refs/heads/release/*
+:refs/heads/hotfix/*
+:refs/heads/develop
+:refs/heads/master
```

- deploy to staging:

```
+:refs/heads/master
+:refs/heads/release/*
+:refs/heads/hotfix/*
```

- deploy to test:

```
+:refs/heads/develop
```

- deploy to production:

```
+:refs/heads/master
```

so this is my setup, now my problems:

- then gitlab trigger teamcity (on merge request) the verify configuration started. but i see following message (for  example):
  **The build was triggered in the branch feature/VTS-610 which does not correspond to any branch monitored by the build VCS roots (the branch is either closed or excluded / not matched by any branch specification). Because of that default branch revisions were set to this build.**

same message i can see if merge request initiated for hotfix branch (of course with another branch name, ie hotfix/VTS-654).

- after hotfix branch merged (we create two merge-request: one to master and one to develop), i can see that deploy to staging was triggered, but deploy to test does not.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, the root cause in my case was the predefined build parameter `teamcity.build.branch` (see [Build Branch Parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html#Build+Branch+Parameters))

The parameter was set in the build configuration of the failing build under "Parameters / Configuration Parameters". As I had no use for this parameter anymore, it was safe to just delete it. I was then able to run the build configuration with any branch that is accepted in the Branch Filter under Version Control Settings.